# mcc structure for google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My partner has unique login credential for all of their accounts and they are wondering if they are able to create an MCC structure or one master manager account for GA accounts. Similar to AdWords. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have a GA360 contract then you can manage your 360 properties and related Google services via a top level entity called an "organization" . Other than that, not. Also might not be really on topic, since SO is about programming problems.

Comment: They don't have GA360. Sadly this was where Google recommend I go with this question.